# Trying to setup binding to a callback with different values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a jquery function that builds a series of buttons and binds them to the callback with different argument values.  The issue I am having is that the callback is always called with the argument value of the last buttons[] value "cancel" no matter which button is clicked.

```
var buttons = ["OK|ok", "Cancel|cancel"];
buildButtons(buttons, function(response){
    alert(response);
});

function buildButtons(buttons){
    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        var btnTitle = buttons[i].split("|")[0];
        var btnName = buttons[i].split("|")[1].toString();
        var btnElem = $('<button/>', {
            type: 'button',
            id: 'btn_' + btnName,
            html: btnTitle,
        })

        $(btnElem).on('click', function () {
            //..some other code
            fnResponse(btnName); //<<------- Issue Should return 'ok' or 'cancel'
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that the callback is always called with the value [btnName] of the last element.. no matter which button is clicked.

Comment: I suggest you change the structure of the buttonlist to an array of objects. Something like `var buttons = [{ OK: 'ok' }, { Cancel: 'cancel' }];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change context for each literal. You can do it with jQuery `each`:

```
function buildButtons(buttons, fnResponse){
    $.each(buttons, function(index, button)) {
        // wrapped into diffent function, context changed
        var btnTitle = button.split("|")[0];
        var btnName = button.split("|")[1].toString();
        var btnElem = $('<button/>', {
            type: 'button',
            id: 'btn_' + btnName,
            html: btnTitle,
        });

        $(btnElem).on('click', function () {
            //..some other code
            fnResponse(btnName); //<<------- Issue Should return 'ok' or 'cancel'
        });
    });
}
```

Another solution: https://gist.github.com/4650951

Some simple example why you need another function: http://jsfiddle.net/nYmtV/

Comment: Just a couple of comments: 1: One `;` is missing after the `btnElem` variable. 2: The click event can be chained directly to the `btnElem`-variable. Also, what difference would the jquery loop make here?

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated the problem in here: http://jsfiddle.net/makque/zgHGc/
I have also included a log element so we could see what's exactly happening inside the code.

If you would try to run the code we can see that the `for` loop was executed and you can see that in our log element only the creation and addition of the button to the `#menu` was executed. And the event handler's code [inside] was skipped...

This therefore proves the definition for event handlers to be true:

> A **JavaScript can be executed when an event occurs**, like when a user clicks on an HTML element.
>
> To execute code when a user clicks on an element, add JavaScript code to an HTML event attribute:
>
> `onclick=JavaScript`

To prove this, when we click the button that's the only time that code will run (as proven from our log)...

**In connection with the problem:**
Local variables or any variable for that matter (i.e., inside a for loop will retain it's last given value)

that means...for example, during

call 0=i: if `var a = i`; a=0

at call 1=i: the value of `var a = i`; a=1

consequently, when u run an eventhandler code using a local variable of the loop, when the loop has already been executed, it will give you it's current value, which in our case is CANCEL...

**So how can we solve this, already?? *&*@&$!**

During code execution of the `for loop`, all lines of code that met the condition are executed, this means the for these lines of codes:

```
1 $(btnElem).on('click', function () {
2    ...
3    alert(btnName);
4 });
```

Lines 1 and 4 were executed, while 2 & 3 were not, since they didn't meet the condition: **on click**

Running lines 1 and 4 meant that the button element has already registered that it has an Eventhandler `onclick`, and is just waiting to be executed.

In summary,
CAUSE: Using the wrong variables
SOLUTION: Use variable in context

```
$(btnElem).on('click', function () {
    fnResponse($(this).html()); //passes the button's title
});
```

At last, we can have a code like these: http://jsfiddle.net/makque/mq9cJ/

Hope I helped! :)

Comment: it makes sense... I was in one of those situations where after several hours of trying to debug, I think I could no longer see the forest for the trees.  I needed to back up and take a fresh look.
Thanks.

Comment: yeah i hear you, when you've been into that deep part of the forest and  it's hard to distinguish each trees since they all look the same... we really need to take a step back, trace our route and have a fresh look on it once again... lol glad i could help! good luck! :)